# Pattern matching for strings in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

Do we have anything in css where styling could be applied to a matching set of keywords?

*For example, I have a list of words {"history","leaders","emotions","time"...}*

*I would like to apply css style to all the keywords matching to above list in the below paragraph.*

“Throughout human **history**, or greatest **leaders** and thinkers have used the power of words to transform our **emotions**, to enlist us in their causes, and to shape the course of **destiny**. Words can not only create **emotions**, they create actions. And from our actions flow the results of our lives.” Tony Robbins

Comment: *"Do we have anything in css where styling could be applied to a matching set of keywords?"* - Nope.

Comment: Nope, you would need `<span class="xxx">History</span>` which can be inserted dynamically with JavaScript.

Comment: You would need to use js to wrap them in a span with a class attached to it - css cannot do this by itself

Comment: **NO**...CSS styles **elements**...it can't detect them.

Comment: with javascript do a replace in the words you want, for example "history" to "<strong>history</strong>"

Comment: You can use - https://markjs.io/

Comment: Thanks all for inputs. I will go for javascript to edit the html code before applying css.

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks all for inputs. I will go for javascript to edit the html code
>   before applying css.

Here is one approach, showing how you can cycle through the array:

```
['history', 'leaders', 'emotions', 'time']
```

and bold each of the words in the text.

```js
var wordsToHighlight = ['history', 'leaders', 'emotions', 'time'];

var paragraph2 = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[1];
var paragraph2Text = paragraph2.innerHTML;
var paragraph2RichText = paragraph2Text;

for (var i = 0; i < wordsToHighlight.length; i++) {
    var regex = new RegExp('('+ wordsToHighlight[i] + ')', 'gi');
    paragraph2RichText = paragraph2RichText.replace(regex, '<strong>$1</strong>');
}

paragraph2.innerHTML = paragraph2RichText;
```

```html
<p>“Throughout human history, or greatest leaders and thinkers have used the power of words to transform our emotions, to enlist us in their causes, and to shape the course of destiny. Words can not only create emotions, they create actions. And from our actions flow the results of our lives.” Tony Robbins</p>
<p>“Throughout human history, or greatest leaders and thinkers have used the power of words to transform our emotions, to enlist us in their causes, and to shape the course of destiny. Words can not only create emotions, they create actions. And from our actions flow the results of our lives.” Tony Robbins</p>
```

Comment: He said "in CSS".

Comment: Your comment above comes across a little hostile, @Rob. The OP included a "javascript" tag. Which you removed. He also wrote: _Thanks all for inputs. I will go for javascript to edit the html code before applying css._ My answer is a response to that comment. I'm sure neither of us know the OP's question better than the OP.

Comment: The mere presence of a [javascript] tag IMHO does not imply that the OP is willing or eager to entertain a JS solution. On the contrary, he repeats "CSS" both in the title and the body of this post. His stated question is "do we have anything in CSS" and "I would like to apply CSS style". We've all seen lots of cases where the OP over-tags their post. In that sense, I agree with the edit to remove the "javascript" tag. If the user had wanted to use JS, it is not unreasonable to assume that he would have added a sentence, *Or, do I have to use JS, and if so how?". (cont'd)

Comment: In any case, if we infer that this question implicitly contains a request for a possible JS solution, then it is a duplicate, since there are dozens if not hundreds of question already on SO about how to mark up words in HTML text. So if that is your understanding of the question, the right thing to do would have been to mark it as a dup (which probably would, rightly, have been contested).